# SpringBoot injection: OK with app, but not with the tests

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-boot, junit4

I've generated a Spring Boot web application using Spring Initializr, using embedded Tomcat and package as an executable JAR file.

This is the main app:

```
package com.tdk;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import com.tdk.repository.JdbcRemoteUnitRepository;


@SpringBootApplication
public class TdkDeviceManagerApp implements CommandLineRunner {


    @Autowired
    private JdbcRemoteUnitRepository jdbcRemoteUnitRepository;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(TdkDeviceManagerApp.class);
        app.run(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... arg0) throws Exception {

        jdbcRemoteUnitRepository.getUnitsWithoutFirmwareInfo();
    }
}
```

This 1 repository class:

```
package com.tdk.repository;

    /**
     * @author  tdk ©
     * @version 1.0
     * @since  15 sept. 2017
     */
    @Transactional
    @Service
    public class JdbcRemoteUnitRepository {
    ..
    }



    @ContextConfiguration(classes={ProductionPersistenceConfig.class})
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    public class JdbcRemoteUnitRepositoryTests {

        @Autowired
        private JdbcRemoteUnitRepository repository;

        @Test   
        public void testGetAllGuardians() throws DataAccessException, SQLException {        
            assertEquals(2, 2);
        }

    }
```

and this is 1 of the test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes={ProductionPersistenceConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class JdbcRemoteUnitRepositoryTests {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcRemoteUnitRepository repository;

    @Test   
    public void testGetAllGuardians() throws DataAccessException, SQLException {        
        assertEquals(2, 2);
    }

}
```

When I start the app. from Eclipse everything is fine, no problems. But when I run the test in Eclipse I got this error:

```
3:24:05.680 [main] ERROR org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@e45f292] to prepare test instance [com.tdk.repository.JdbcRemoteUnitRepositoryTests@5383967b]
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.tdk.repository.JdbcRemoteUnitRepositoryTests': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.tdk.repository.JdbcRemoteUnitRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.tdk.repository.JdbcRemoteUnitRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Because you aren't using Spring Boot to run your tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the annotation `@SpringBootTest`.

Moreover you can also find useful the annotation `@Profile("test")`, exploit it allows you to set another database for test environment.